# E-Commerce Payment Gateway - Funds transfer from one customer to another

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway, braintree, payment-processing

We are developing a javascript based Mobile Web app (using cordova) for iOS and Android and need to use a payment gateway. The use case is similar to Amazon, where our site is just a middleman between buyers and sellers:

When a buyer purchases an item from a seller, we need to charge the buyer's credit/debit card (or) bank account, keep a margin amount for using our platform and then transfer the remaining funds to seller's bank account (essentially the seller incurring the platform's service charges).

Can Stripe or any other payments gateway be used for this specific purpose of crediting/depositing money directly to a user's (seller's) bank account. Is there a payment gateway that works in multiple countries (USA & India most importantly) for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much what [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide) is for, and works globally.